# SendGrid requires me to use my Username and Password... but they never gave me a password

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  password:  ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  domain:    'heroku.com',
  address:   'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  port:      587,
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Trying to integrate this, but I keep getting username/password errors. When I added Sendgrid as a Heroku add-on, it wouldn't tell me the password it assigned me. It simply said "Your Password". Well, that doesn't mean anything when my heroku password doesn't work. So, I'm in a rut.

Further, I can't create a new password without knowing the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added the Heroku addon, you should be able to get your username and password by running:

```
$ heroku config:get SENDGRID_USERNAME
appXYZ@heroku.com

$ heroku config:get SENDGRID_PASSWORD
password
```

They should be assigned to environment variables under your application on Heroku.

Via https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on